# Issue in reading newly uploaded image

Tags: php

I am uploading an image and storing the image path in database. Coding for this is as below

```
<?php
     if( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES[$objName]['tmp_name'], trim($this->upload_path.$img_name_str )) ) {
                    $fNames[] = $img_name_str;
                    chmod(trim($this->upload_path.$img_name_str ), 777);
                }
?>
```

Image uploaded into folder correctly. But the problem is permission for the image is set as 01411 even though I set folder permission as 777. This causes I am unable to show the image in front end. Please advice.

I am facing this issue only in server.

Comment: can you check path name is correct ?

Comment: Yes path name is correct. Problem only with permission. If I manually give permission to the image as 777 its working fine. The problem is while uploading permission set as 01411

Comment: Maybe change your `umask`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From php.net

> Note:
>
> The current user is the user under which PHP runs. It is probably not
>   the same user you use for normal shell or FTP access. The mode can be
>   changed only by user who owns the file on most systems.
>
> Note:
>
> This function will not work on remote files as the file to be examined
>   must be accessible via the server's filesystem.
>
> Note:
>
> When safe mode is enabled, PHP checks whether the files or directories
>   you are about to operate on have the same UID (owner) as the script
>   that is being executed. In addition, you cannot set the SUID, SGID and
>   sticky bits.